# Positional argument issues within creating classes in Python

Tags: python

## Update

I have currently trying to change theclas into

```
def getPlayerMove(getNewBoard,playerTile):
    b=BoardHandler()
    b.getNewBoard
    # Let the player type in their move.
    # Returns the move as [x, y] 
    DIGITS1TO8 = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10'.split()
    while True:
        print('Din tur B')
        move = input().lower()
```

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the definition of `drawBoard`.

Comment: Please provide full error message and traceback.

Comment: @chepner check updated version!

Comment: @albert simply when I have a mainboard in a definition from within the class it tells me that ex  `Test123(mainboard) takes one positional argument but 2 was given `

Comment: You have several problems. `getNewBoard` returns nothing, but you use the return as the parameter to both `drawBoard` and `resetBoard` neither of which take a parameter.

Comment: In addition to @quamrana: Please fix indentation and code formatting. Please provide a fully [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on how classes work in Python, specifically the meaning of the `self` argument in member functions.

Comment: @quamrana Okay, is there a way to change that into taking the parameter and making `getNewBoard` retuning the boardlist in which the current moves happends?

Comment: @Pythongirl: Seems like you need to provide an additional argument to the `self` argument in method definition inside the class definition. However, just assuming since your code is not executable.

Comment: @albert should I post my entire code?

Comment: Well, since you have defined a class, its usual for member functions to operate on attributes of the class without needing extra parameters. That is, why return something from `getNewBoard` only to pass it into other member functions?

Comment: @Pythongirl: A [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is a reduced, but fully working, code-snippet in order to reproduce your issue and make helping you easier. Since you are a new member on SO, you might have a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Fix your formatting first. Python is very sensitive to formatting.

Comment: Yes it is weird because it's part of my old code I am currently translating onto this class-based version, yet I do not understand how I can pass on the mainboard variable without having it within the member functions @quamrana

Comment: Formatting better. How about just not passing parameters to `drawBoard` and `resetBoard`. These methods seem to do the right thing without being called with a parameter.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 1):

Your board is saved in the `self.board` field of a `BoardHandler` instance, so any manipulation on the board should be interfaced through the `BoardHandler` methods.

In your code you assign `mainboard = b.getNewBoard()`. That method manipulates the board in the `BoardHandler` instance `b` and returns `None`.

So actually `mainboard = None`.

You pass it as a parameter to `b.resetBoard()` (which doesn't take parameters) and that's where the error comes from.

Try to implement all of your board manipulation through `BoardHandler` methods.

Comment: Can you give me an example of implementing the mainboard through the Class?

Comment: @Pythongirl: Your `BoardHandler` code is just fine. Just stop passing `mainboard` created in `main1v1` to all of the methods of `BoardHandler`. eg instead of `b.getValidMoves(mainBoard,playerTile)` use `b.getValidMoves(playerTile)`

Comment: Yeah ^^, but the question stands, how do I manipulate for example resetBoard() using getNewBoard() without returning it to none

Comment: I would add some more board manipulating methods such as `make_a_move()` , `print_board()` and some other stuff you find useful for making board handling easier.

Comment: @quamrana but if so, my entire program stops working, as the list created in getNewBoard is needed for the tiles to place down

Comment: It looks like your code should be `b.getNewBoard()` then `b.resetBoard()`.

Comment: @nutmeg64 so you see no "easy way out" implementing `getNewBoard` into said `def` within the classes?

Comment: Your goal is making `BoardHandler` do all those things for you and all you need to do is tell him the size and "what to do". `getNewBoard()` and `resetBoard()` for me mean the same. A reset board of size X is the same as a new board of size X. What manipulation will you do on a board? I think: Create (or Reset for that matter), Print, Make a move (or Change state). Those seem like a complete set of actions for a game board. If you feel there is something I'm missing then add it.

Comment: What if I picked the `getNewBoard` into one of my attributes using it from thereon calling on it from the classes needed?

Comment: @nutmeg64 No you are quite right, I have just assumed that is the problem because when I run my current code, never passes the turn to the "other player", which made me suspect the `mainBoard`

Comment: After you created an instance of `BoardHandler` (which you named `b`) you do not need to assign it to any other variables. Just manipulate the board like `b.some_manipulating_method()`

Comment: Well maybe this is not the correct way to ask this, but why does then the program just stops at 'player' and do not continue?

Comment: did you remove __all__ of `mainBoard` from your code? Try to play with it a bit and if you get stuck and can't figure out why, consider posting a new question or editing this one. If you want you can get a code review at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.